# Can't install wwwsqldesigner on Nginx + Postgresql

Tags: php, postgresql, nginx

I'm trying to install [wwwsqldesigner v2.7](http://s://github.com/ondras/wwwsqldesigner) tool to my Nginx server but can't connect it to my postgresql database

Actually I've done everything according to manual, have created `wwwsqldesigner` database and `wwwsqldesigner` user, and changed the `index.php` in a `/backend/php-postgresql/index.php` accordingly

My `nginx.conf` file is following, sqldesigner is in `sub-uri` of my server:

```
location /sqldesigner {
                alias /opt/sqldesigner/wwwsqldesigner;
                autoindex on;
           #     auth_basic "Restricted";          #For Basic Auth
           #     auth_basic_user_file /opt/nginx/.htpasswd;  #For Basic Auth

                location ~ \.php$ {
                        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
                        fastcgi_index index.php;
                        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $request_filename;
                        include fastcgi_params;
                }
        }
```

First of all when I push a button `list-items` from `server-box` I get the list of my files inside `php-postgresql` directory as following:

```
<html>
<head><title>Index of /sqldesigner/backend/php-postgresql/</title></head>
<body bgcolor="white">
<h1>Index of /sqldesigner/backend/php-postgresql/</h1><hr><pre><a href="../">../</a>
<a href="README">README</a>                                             19-Sep-2015 12:28                 719
<a href="database.sql">database.sql</a>                                       19-Sep-2015 12:28                 163
<a href="index.php">index.php</a>                                          20-Sep-2015 18:44                9920
</pre><hr></body>
</html>
```

When I press `save` nothing is written in my database, and when I try to load something back I get an error: `XML error: Null document`

Definitely I done something wrong, but can't realise what wrong.

Thank you for any help.

**UPDATE**:

In `nginx/logs/error.log` I've found a following record:

```
2015/09/20 15:01:46 [error] 1947#0: *6 directory index of "/opt/sqldesigner/wwwsqldesigner/backend/php-postgresql/" is forbidden, client: 120.120.120.120, server: example.com, request: "POST /sqldesigner/backend/php-postgresql/?action=save&keyword=test HTTP/1.1", host: "example.com", referrer: "https://example.com/sqldesigner/"
```

Now I understand that it's permission issue, but to whom I need to give permission?

**UPDATE 2**:
After a while and reading manual I understand that I don't need to set a permission I need to point Nginx to `index.php` file. After I've added the following line: `index index.php index.html index.htm;` to `nginx.conf` it began behave more predictable and gives the following error `Server response: Internal Server Error` when I try to save table. In `error.log` of Nginx I see that nginx return error 500. Now I'm looking for a solution from this point.

**UPDATE 3**:

In `/nginx/error.log` I've found the following error:

`FastCGI sent in stderr: "PHP message: PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function pg_connect() in /opt/sqldesigner/wwwsqldesigner/backend/php-postgresql/index.php on line 42" while reading response header from upstream...`

google said me to install `php5-pgsql` package to overcome it, after I've done it the next error was: `PHP message: PHP Warning:  pg_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in /opt/sqldesigner/wwwsqldesigner/backend/php-postgresql/index.php on line 221" while reading response header from upstream, client:`

Continue digging...

**UPDATE 4 and last one :)**

I forget to give privileges to `wwwsqldesigner` user, and this command from `psql` finally has solved my problem:

`GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON TABLE wwwsqldesigner to wwwsqldesigner;`

**So, just read logs, manuals, some google and [sky's the limit](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=d3vOeCkeCNA)**